# ListContourPlot3D is blank

Tags: plotting

I want to do a ListContourPlot3D.
The list of data is as follows

```
normplotP1={{0, 0, 2, 0.13188}, {0, 0, 3, 0.13188}, {30, 0, 1, 0.13188}, {30, 0, 
  2, 0.13188}, {30, 0, 3, 0.13188}, {60, 0, 1, 0.13188}, {60, 0, 2, 
  0.13188}, {60, 0, 3, 0.13188}, {90, 0, 1, 0.13188}, {90, 0, 2, 
  0.13188}, {90, 0, 3, 0.13188}, {120, 0, 1, 0.13188}, {120, 0, 2, 
  0.13188}, {120, 0, 3, 0.13188}, {0, 0.6, 1, 0.105504}, {0, 0.6, 2, 
  0.105504}, {0, 0.6, 3, 0.105504}, {30, 0.6, 1, 0.105504}, {30, 0.6, 
  2, 0.105504}, {30, 0.6, 3, 0.105504}, {60, 0.6, 1, 0.105504}, {60, 
  0.6, 2, 0.105504}, {60, 0.6, 3, 0.105504}, {90, 0.6, 1, 
  0.105504}, {90, 0.6, 2, 0.105504}, {90, 0.6, 3, 0.105504}, {120, 
  0.6, 1, 0.105504}, {120, 0.6, 2, 0.105504}, {120, 0.6, 3, 
  0.105504}, {0, 1.2, 1, 0.079128}, {0, 1.2, 2, 0.079128}, {0, 1.2, 3,
   0.079128}, {30, 1.2, 1, 0.079128}, {30, 1.2, 2, 0.079128}, {30, 
  1.2, 3, 0.079128}, {60, 1.2, 1, 0.079128}, {60, 1.2, 2, 
  0.079128}, {60, 1.2, 3, 0.079128}, {90, 1.2, 1, 0.079128}, {90, 1.2,
   2, 0.079128}, {90, 1.2, 3, 0.079128}, {120, 1.2, 1, 
  0.079128}, {120, 1.2, 2, 0.079128}, {120, 1.2, 3, 0.079128}, {0, 
  1.8, 1, 0.052752}, {0, 1.8, 2, 0.052752}, {0, 1.8, 3, 
  0.052752}, {30, 1.8, 1, 0.052752}, {30, 1.8, 2, 0.052752}, {30, 1.8,
   3, 0.052752}, {60, 1.8, 1, 0.052752}, {60, 1.8, 2, 0.052752}, {60, 
  1.8, 3, 0.052752}, {90, 1.8, 1, 0.052752}, {90, 1.8, 2, 
  0.052752}, {90, 1.8, 3, 0.052752}, {120, 1.8, 1, 0.052752}, {120, 
  1.8, 2, 0.052752}, {120, 1.8, 3, 0.052752}, {0, 2.4, 1, 
  0.026376}, {0, 2.4, 2, 0.026376}, {0, 2.4, 3, 0.026376}, {30, 2.4, 
  1, 0.026376}, {30, 2.4, 2, 0.026376}, {30, 2.4, 3, 0.026376}, {60, 
  2.4, 1, 0.026376}, {60, 2.4, 2, 0.026376}, {60, 2.4, 3, 
  0.026376}, {90, 2.4, 1, 0.026376}, {90, 2.4, 2, 0.026376}, {90, 2.4,
   3, 0.026376}, {120, 2.4, 1, 0.026376}, {120, 2.4, 2, 
  0.026376}, {120, 2.4, 3, 0.026376}, {0, 2.9, 1, 0.004396}, {0, 2.9, 
  2, 0.004396}, {0, 2.9, 3, 0.004396}, {30, 2.9, 1, 0.004396}, {30, 
  2.9, 2, 0.004396}, {30, 2.9, 3, 0.004396}, {60, 2.9, 1, 
  0.004396}, {60, 2.9, 2, 0.004396}, {60, 2.9, 3, 0.004396}, {90, 2.9,
   1, 0.004396}, {90, 2.9, 2, 0.004396}, {90, 2.9, 3, 0.004396}, {120,
   2.9, 1, 0.004396}, {120, 2.9, 2, 0.004396}, {120, 2.9, 3, 
  0.004396}, {0, 0, 1, 0.13188}}
```

Now if I try and solve

```
ListContourPlot3D[normplotP1, Contours -> 1
 , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

I get a blank contour plot.
What is the correct way to plot this data?

Comment: But `ListContourPlot3D` is means for 3d data, and your matrix is 90 by 4.  You could always use `MatrixPlot[normplotP1, AspectRatio -> 1]` to get a matrix view of the data.

Comment: @Nasser, the second form of `ListContourPlot3D` in the docs is of the form `{x, y, z, f}`, precisely as OP has given. It should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListContourPlot3D[normplotP1, Contours -> 1, MaxPlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

```
ListContourPlot3D[normplotP1, Contours -> 1, MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ViewPoint -> {1, 1.5, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @rewi! Is there a way to make the graph look like a continuous surface instead of separate items?

Comment: @GEF play with `ViewPoint`